# R: Select a number conditionally from a sequence based on the value of another random selected number from the same range

Tags: r, apply

xc is a randomly sampled variable between 61-69. yc is a sequence 61-69.
I am trying to select a single value from yc conditionally dependent on the value of xc such that the sum adds to 130. I have attached my 3 attempts so far:

```
xc<-sample(seq(from = 61, to = 69, by = 1), size = 1, replace = FALSE)
yc<-seq(61,69,1)

#returns the logical sequence
df<-sapply(xc,function(a) xc+yc == 130 )
df

# outputs the list of sums
library(magicfor)
magic_for(silent = TRUE)
for (i in 1) {
 (xc+yc[i] == 130)
 put (yc, xc , yc+xc)
}
magic_result_as_dataframe()      
       
#returns logical sequence
yci<-function(a){
    a <- yc+xc==130
    return(a)
    }

yci()
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: Your first try with `yc[sapply(xc,function(a) xc+yc == 130)]` should return the correct `yc` value. Or simply `yc[xc + yc == 130]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't you just need `130 - xc` to get `yc` ?

Also, I don't think it is necessary to have `yc` already defined (as `yc<-seq(61,69,1)`) since it is going to be exactly one number given `xc` which will satisfy the condition `xc + yc = 130`.

```
return_yc <- function(xc) 130 - xc
set.seed(123)
xc <- sample(seq(from = 61, to = 69, by = 1), size = 1)
xc
#[1] 63

return_yc(xc)
#[1] 67
```